# Why does this.renderChart not exist on CombinedVueInstance?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

The Vue component I created with TypeScript, and vue-chartjs, keeps giving me an problem of `this.renderChart` not existing. I can't seem to find a way to define it.

> Property 'renderChart' does not exist on type '`CombinedVueInstance<Vue, unknown, unknown, unknown, Readonly<Record<"chartData" | "options", any>>>`'.

Whenever I use `console.log()` to the define `this` it shows me the function existing, along with and throws these Exceptions

```
renderChart: ƒ ()
arguments: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.invokeGetter (<anonymous>:1:142)]
caller: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.invokeGetter (<anonymous>:1:142)]
length: 2
name: "bound renderChart"
__proto__: ƒ ()
[[TargetFunction]]: ƒ renderChart(data, options)
[[BoundThis]]: VueComponent
[[BoundArgs]]: Array(0)
styles: (...)
width: (...)
```

This is the component

*LineChart.vue*

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";
import { Line, mixins } from "vue-chartjs";
export default Vue.extend({
  name: "LineChart",
  extends: Line,
  mixins: [mixins.reactiveProp],
  props: ["chartData", "options"],
  mounted() {
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options);
  }
});
</script>
```

Should I try and find a way around it, or is there mess a up on the way I called the function? 
I've looked at the vue-chartjs [docs](https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#updating-charts) and the function is called the same way, I assume they don't use TypeScript.

Comment: This is a compile-time error from Typescript. You need to inform the compiler that your `LineChart` component implements `{ renderChart(chartData: any, options: any) }`

Comment: Where do I go to tell the compiler?

Comment: Quick solution is to define an interface and use `(this.$refs.whatever as LineChartInterface).renderChart(...)`

Comment: See https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/94

Comment: In the post you put that replaces this one, they're using vue-class-component.

Comment: There's more than one answer

Comment: Alright, appreciate the help.